# How to use activity output with period in fieldname JSON in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am currently setting up a pipeline, where I need to extract a value from a JSON response (Web activity output). This output has a period in the fieldname. How do I use this value?

The simplified output is as follows:

```
{
"aud": "https://login.----.com/auth/authentication/resources",
"abc.organisationUserCode": "----",
"abc.clusterUrl": "https://url-to-use.com",
}
```

If I use `@activity('GetclusterUrl').output.abc.clusterUrl` I get the following error:

```
The expression 'activity('GetclusterUrl').output.abc.clusterUrl' cannot be evaluated because property 'abc' doesn't exist
```

Is there a way to for example use an escape character to be able to use this value further down the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this expression:

```
@activity('GetclusterUrl').output['abc.organisationUserCode']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried every single option with brackets, no brackets, parenthesis etc. Didn't try this one, very much appreciated!!